# Intellij IDEA 2019.1: what is a keyboard shortcut for "Merge from..." (Subversion working copies information)?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a keybinding to open: Version Control tool window | Subversion Working Copies Information Tab | Merge from

I can't find information about it in Intellij help nor in IDE itself. 
Page https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/select-branch.html tells about Shift+Enter combination which doesn't work (Intellij IDEA version 2019.1). I cannot navigate to link "Merge from..." with cursor keys either (I can select Refresh but no other option on this tab).
I was also looking for appropriate option in Settings -> Keymap to assign some key to it but I only see option for Git merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no keymap entry for this action, unfortunately - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156269